# How can I properly init pages in .netcore using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, .net-core, pageobjects

Following other examples, I was previously following the method of `PageFactory.InitElements(driver, page)` to initialize my pages before calling the methods to find elements on those specific pages.

However, seems that PageFactory is now obsolete with .netcore as stated here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4387

The issue I am coming across is initializing my pages for an automation framework for selenium without the PageFactory.Init I used/saw in other usages. I cannot seem to get passed the null reference exception for the example code below. This is what I have set up right now:

Using latest .netcore, selenium.chrome.webdriver, selenium.webdriver, selenium support and xunit

Example setup:

**Test.cs**

```cs
[Fact]
public void CanLogin()
{
    Pages.Login.Login("username", "password");
    Assert.True(true);
}
```

**Pages.cs**

//This is where I want to initialize my login and return it but having my difficulty. This is COMPLETELY PSEUDO...this is just where I want it to happen

```cs
public LoginPage Login
{
    return Init LoginPage here;
}
```

**LoginPage.cs**

```cs
private IWebElement userNameTextField;
private IWebElement passwordTextField;

public void Login(string userName, string password)
{
    userNameTextField.SendKeys(userName);
    passwordTextField.SendKeys(password);
}
```

As soon as it hits `Pages.Login.Login()` it will fail saying `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I have tried many things but cannot find the right pattern to follow to be able to initiate all needed pages in my Pages.cs, such as: LoginPage

Any ideas?

Comment: Temporarily I found this: https://github.com/Dreamescaper/DotNetSeleniumExtras/tree/master/src/PageObjects

But any other ideas/thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Create a instance of the page classes and pass the instance in the test. See the solution below

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanLogin()
    {
        Page LoginPage = PageInitialization.Login;
        LoginPage.Login("username", "password");
    }

    public class PageInitialization
    {
        private Page loginPage;

        public PageInitialization()
        {
            loginPage = new Page();
        }

        public static Page Login
        {
            get { return Instance.loginPage; }
        }

        private static PageInitialization Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return new PageInitialization();
            }
        }
    }


    public class Page
    {
        private IWebElement userNameTextField;

        private IWebElement passwordTextField;

        public void Login(string userName, string password)
        {

            userNameTextField.SendKeys(userName);
            passwordTextField.SendKeys(password);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I did try applying this and still had issues. However, I will play around with the above and see if there is somewhere else I can go with this idea!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by SeleniumExtras.PageObjects

then i was able to follow the pattern found from original posting above: PageFactory.InitElements(driver, page)